# Is there a way to order children of post?

Tags: posts, get-children

there is a main post:

```
$parent = wp_insert_post([
    'post_type' => 'parent',
    'post_name' => 'test parent'
]);
```

and the children:

```
$child1 = wp_insert_post([
    'post_type' => 'child',
    'post_name' => 'test child1'
]);
$child2 = wp_insert_post([
    'post_type' => 'child',
    'post_name' => 'test child2'
]);
$child3 = wp_insert_post([
    'post_type' => 'child',
    'post_name' => 'test child3'
]);
```

lets match them:

```
wp_update_post(
    array('ID' => $child1, 'post_parent' => $parent)
);
wp_update_post(
    array('ID' => $child2, 'post_parent' => $parent)
);
wp_update_post(
    array('ID' => $child3, 'post_parent' => $parent)
);
```

finally to list them:

```
$children = get_children(['post_parent' => $parent]);
```

this is theoretically seems to be OK, but it only describes the relation itself, not the order. What if I want to order the children? How to do it?

Comment: Save ordinal number as meta field `child_no` for each child post. Then, when selecting, sort post by this meta field.

Comment: seems like this is the easiest way

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with the Order property that already exists, `menu_order`? Not clear why a custom field is necessary here?

Comment: `menu_order` is available for page and custom post type. Did I miss something? @JacobPeattie

Comment: I'm assuming these are pages or custom post types, because posts don't have parents.

Comment: You are right..

Comment: @nmr your solution seems to be OK (altough a bit performance overkill, since now it needs another join), could you post it so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable in the `get_children()` query, try the following:
Take a look at the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) entry of `get_children()`. You will see that `get_children()` uses the same `args` as `get_posts()`. If you than [look at](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) `get_posts()` you will see that you have 2 order arguments to work with:

```
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
```

For all possible `orderby` and `order` parameters, you can take a look at [WP_Query codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: but by wp_update_post, I cant see  the way to set a direct sequence

Comment: Do you want to save a specific order number to each post? Like its done on normal pages in the Page Attributes.